# Impossible to get Outlook 2016 to connect to Office 365 account

Tags: outlook, microsoft-office-365

I have looked at many posts and articles regarding this issue, and I have tried at least half a dozen solutions. None of them work.

My company has recently changed all their mail accounts to 365. Prior to that, I was able to connect (at home) to Exchange perfectly from my workstation at home (no need for VPN or anything).

Strangely, I have recently connected a notebook at home (same network, of course) to 365 with Outlook 2016 (the exact same installation package). With that, I can safely assume it is not a network issue.

Steps I have taken:

- completely removed Office 2016, all of its files, and all (I think) registry entries, installed Office again;
- used "Microsoft Support and Recovery Assistant". This *almost* gets it done, but fails at the end. Right at the very beginning, it opens my company's corporate login form, which I fill with my credentials. The process goes on, apparently all good, just to fail at the last step. Sometimes it will point to a CNAME problem, sometimes it will say the password is wrong, and at times it will even say it has solved the problem. When this last result is the case, Outlook won't even start because of a corrupted profile;
- copied the Outlook profile from my notebook (where Outlook 2016 works fine);
- tried every possible scenario connected to the company's VPN/not connected to the VPN;
- completely disabling all types of Windows firewalls;

I'm at a loss here.
Every single time, no matter what I do I get "We're unable to connect right now".

Please help. I've already spend hours and hours trying to fix that.

Comment: Is your Office 365 account MFA enabled?

Comment: What is the exact sub version of Outlook 2016? There have been strange problems with Office 365 mail lately. Updating the Office 2016 (or Office 365) has helped.

Comment: No MFA, but there is a need for a corporate login. The exact version of Office is 2016 Pro Plus.

Answer (score 0):

Do your company use ADFS for SSO?
I suggest you test this account via OWA in your company network firstly. This could isolate whether this issue is caused by account, then test outlook with company network.

Comment: No. We use NDS. At work there are no problems, of course. The problem is when I try to connect from home.

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t know NDS, is it for SSO?
Since there is no error within company, I suspect this is caused by network. It seems that your PC cannot resolve the service endpoint correctly outside company. Or you could use some network monitor to check the what request is blocked.